# sorting NSMutableArray contain NSArray using sortedArrayUsingComparator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, date-sorting

I got problem for sorting array of nsdate.
so i have array of date inside nsmutablearray

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSArray *arrString = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2012-05-01", @"2012-02-01", @"2012-22-03", @"2012-05-01", @"2012-15-01", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:arrString.count];
for (NSString *item in arrString) {
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:item];
    [arrDate addObject:date];
}
```

as i saw in many cases they use code like this to sort array:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrDate sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
    return [((NSDate *)firstObject) compare:((NSDate *)secondObject)];
}];
```

i tried to put my array on it, but not worked.
Anyone can help me how actully best way to sort nsmutablearray contain nsdate. I want to put the latest date at top of the index array.

So the real question is, how can i sort data inside arrDate?

Thank you.

Comment: "i tried to put my array on it, but not worked." What didn't work? Was the array empty? Did it crash from trying to insert a nil date? Did the array just not sort? Because the obvious thing I can see is that your date format does not match the dates in the array. Remove the `hh:mm:ss` since the strings contain no time information.

Comment: dont worry the format just fine, it just typo when i post it. Now it fixed. My problem is how i can sort the date inside the array. The sorting didnt work, how can i use sortedArrayUsingComparator for my nsmutablearray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format does not match the date strings you are using.

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
```

means the dates you supply should look something like:

```
2012-05-09 15:54:21
        ^^ Day
     ^^ Month
```

i.e. your strings are missing the hours, minutes and seconds  and you have some dates with month 22 and month 15.  If a date formatter can't parse a date, I think it returns nil which would mean you are trying to put nil into an array, which will cause an exception.

**Edit**

To actually sort the dates, your sample code looks OK except that you want most recent first, so reverse the `compare:`

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrDate sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
     return [secondObject compare: firstObject];
}];
```

Or with a mutable array, you can sort in place:

```
[arrDate sortUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
     return [secondObject compare: firstObject];
}];
```

Comment: sorry the format doesnt matter, it just typo when i posted the question, i've fixed my code. So we can back to the original question how can i sort the array contain nsdate?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, i think it works with your method, thank you. But i curious why this string -> @"2012-05-08 19:00:43" not works with NSDateFormatter @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" if i using [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2012-05-08 19:00:43"]; the return is nil. do u know why?

Comment: ahh i got it.., the format should be @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" instead of @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" . tx anyway